# Accessing JSON received via POST from file

Tags: go, martini

I'm building a RESTful API using Martini and have a hard time accessing the contents of book.json sent to my service via

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/books" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @book.json
```

book.json is not a binary file but a simple text file containing a JSON array. How can I access the transmitted JSON? PostForm on the http.Request is empty.

Comment: Could you show your handler processing the POST request?

Comment: did you call `request.ParseForm()` before accessing the `PostForm`?   Please show your go handler code AND data structures AND json, as all of them are necessary to pinpoint the problem!

Comment: Can you try `book:=Book{};json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&book)`?

Comment: or what you want is just prin it out? Maybe with `ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)`

Comment: Please show the handler of /books

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but you are probably looking for Martini Binding

https://github.com/martini-contrib/binding

```
m.Post("/contact/submit", binding.Bind(ContactForm{}), func(contact ContactForm) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Name: %s\nEmail: %s\nMessage: %s",
        contact.Name, contact.Email, contact.Message)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have data in request.Body that you can demarshal.
Imho this aticle explains well the problem: http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/11/30/fear-and-loathing-with-golang-and-angular-js/